# Workflow of a 'for' loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have written this code to sort an array by descending order, created two versions of it with both looking almost identical, but the first one works while the second one doesn't. I need someone to explain what's going on here.

Version 1:

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const newArry = []

for (;myArr.length > 0;) {
    let a = myArr[0]

    for (b of myArr) {b > a ? a = b :  null}

    newArry.push(a)
    myArr.splice(myArr.indexOf(a), 1)
}


console.log(newArry) // [ 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

Version 2:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    let a = myArr[0]

    for (b of myArr) {b > a ? a = b :  null}

    newArry.push(a)
    myArr.splice(myArr.indexOf(a), 1)
}

console.log(newArry) // [ 6, 5, 4 ]
```

Comment: yes I mean array it's a typo

Comment: The `newArr` length decreases by 1 each iteration due to the splice, therefore starting from a length of 6, after 3 iterations 3 items are sorted into the new array and the length of `newArr` is now 3 and equal to `i` - exiting the for loop.

Comment: Why not just use `Array.prototype.sort`?

Comment: @Dai I want to do that without builtin methods

Comment: @Vcoder but `indexOf` and `push` are built-in methods 

Comment: @Dai Is not about using builtin methods is about finding a different solution

Comment: @Vcoder There's only a small number of different sorting algorithms you can really reimplement yourself (merge sort, quicksort, bubble-sort). I assume this is for CS undergraduate-level homework or something? I hope you're not doing this for any professional/production work.

Comment: @Dai Of course not for work, I'm just practicing

Comment: @Dai Why only those three? You left out insertion, selection, and heap sorts at the very least, for the common basics.

Comment: @DaveNewton Because JavaScript arrays are an abstraction over fundamentally different implementations hidden by the JS engine (source: I used to work on Chakra) it means that it's very difficult to  implement some sort algorithms that depend on precise runtime characteristics of array operations.

Comment: @Dai I don’t understand. Sorting is sorting; you’re saying those can’t be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By logging the results of each iteration in your Version 2 code, we see that the loop actually only runs 3 times.

[image]

This is because `i < myArr.length` is being evaluated as `false`. `i` is increased by 1 for each iteration, as `myArr.length` is decreased for each iteration. The loops breaks when `i=3` and `myArr.length=3`.

Your Version 1 code works because it it essentially a while loop which breaks when `myArr.length` hits `0`. Which happens only after 6 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `i < myArr.length` is the problem here.

```js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const newArry = [];

for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    let a = myArr[0];

    for (b of myArr) {b > a ? a = b :  null}

    newArry.push(a);
    myArr.splice(myArr.indexOf(a), 1);
}

console.log(newArry); // [ 6, 5, 4 ]
```

Since you're removing the item from `myArr`, its length is changing.

At the start of the loop, `i = 0` and `myArr.length = 6`.
During the second iteration, `i = 1` and `myArr.length = 5`.
Beginning of the 3rd iteration, `i = 2` and `myArr.length = 4`.
At the end of 3rd iteration, `i = 3` and `myArr.length = 3`.
During the beginning of 4th iteration, the condition `i < myArr.length` doesn't hold anymore and the loop exit out.

**Solutions:**
So what are the possible workarounds to this problem? I can think of two.

```js
const myArr = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const newArry = [];

for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    let a = myArr[0];

    for (b of myArr) { if (b > a) a = b; }

    newArry.push(a);
    myArr.splice(myArr.indexOf(a), 1, undefined);
}

console.log(newArry); // [ 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1 ]
```

When removing the item from `myArr`, fill it with `undefined`. You might wonder why not `null`. That's because it will coalesce to 0 when you're checking it against any number. So if you've any negetive number in your list, the condition `null > negetive_number` would be true.

Ok let's move on to the next method!

```js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const newArry = [];

for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length;) {
    let a = myArr[0];

    for (b of myArr) {if (b > a) a = b; }

    newArry.push(a);
    myArr.splice(myArr.indexOf(a), 1);
}

console.log(newArry); // [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Remove the `i++` thing altogether.

Honestly this isn't very good way to sort arrays and I would recommend you to use `Array.prototype.sort()` instead.